# npm run cannot run an script found in node_modules/.bin/___

Tags: npm

I installed [sequelize-cli](https://github.com/sequelize/cli):

`npm install sequelize-cli --save`

I have only installed it locally, **not** globally. My local project is at `C:/git/craft`

I try to execute it by typing `sequelize-cli`, but this doesn't work; I forget I must type `node_modules/.bin/sequelize-cli`

I want to use `npm run sequelize-cli`, expecting this will be a shortcut. The [`npm-run-script`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/run-script) documentation says:

> In addition to the shell's pre-existing PATH, **npm run adds
>   node_modules/.bin to the PATH provided to scripts**. Any binaries
>   provided by **locally**-installed dependencies can be used **without the
>   node_modules/.bin prefix**

And yet, when I try to run the script:

```
  "scripts": {
      "sequelize-cli":"sequelize-cli"
    },
```

The result fails:

```
NND@usrem-nnd MINGW64 /c/git/craft (master)
$ npm run sequelize-cli -- --help

> craft@0.0.0 sequelize-cli C:\git\craft
> sequelize-cli "--help"

'sequelize-cli' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.16299
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "sequelize-cli" "--" "--help"
```

I couldn't find similar questions/issues online (specifically re: `node_modules/.bin/____`)

Some Github issues [mention that `yarn` should work](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/1657#issuecomment-259007494), (but also say that `npm` should work as I expect!.) <del>As a workaround I will just install `sequelize-cli` globally.</del>      I can install `sequelize-cli` globally, but then running `sequelize-cli` still produces "command not found". This led me to see my silly mistake...

Answer (score 2):

I had the same question as you. You may have the same problem

Finally, I found it's caused by **my project folder has invalid letter**.

Change your project folder name and try again.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure you are referencing a script that exists! I wasn't! In fact, `npm run` was just revealing the obvious problem: the script `sequelize-cli` doesnt exist *anywhere on the computer*!

... The script is called `sequelize`, even though it comes from a project called `sequelize-cli`. `package.json` `"scripts"` value will determine which scripts can be run; the correct `package.json` should map the script **`"sequelize"`** to the nodejs command `sequelize`:

```
  "scripts": {
      "start": "node ./bin/www",
      "sequelize":"sequelize"
    },
```

`npm run sequelize`  now works...

My mistake... this answer can be deleted if it's unhelpful.